# Golang: ignore position of flag argument

Tags: go

This is my very first interaction with Go after learning some Python for a couple of months. I'm building a simple utility that takes command line arguments and returns results.

```
list := flag.Bool("list", false, "List existing URLs")
url := flag.String("lu", "", "original URL including https:// or http://")
```

And then I have logic to check the inputs:

```
if *url == "" && *list == false {
        fmt.Println("Provide correct input values")
        flag.PrintDefaults()
        os.Exit(1)
    } else if *list == true && *url != "" {
        fmt.Println("Choose either -list or -lu")
        flag.PrintDefaults()
        os.Exit(1)
    } else if *url == "" && *list == true {
        fmt.Println("Only listing URLs")
        listUrls()
    } else if *url != "" && *list == false {
        fmt.Println("Your URL: ", Url)
    }
```

My problem is that when I execute

```
go run main.go -list true -lu http://google.com
```

It returns the list of URLs, but when I run

```
go run main.go -lu http://google.com -list true
```

it returns

```
Choose either -list or -lu
```

Am I missing something obvious? It seems that it cares about the sequence of the arguments but I can't find anything that confirms it.

Comment: `list` is a `bool` argument, it checks for existence of `list`, not whether if its value is true or false. If you want to pass true/false, use `-list=true`.

Comment: Thanks! I see it now. It's mentioned in doc(which I overlooked of course): https://golang.org/pkg/flag/. I missed that bool argument can't be passed as "-list true" but has to be "-list=true". Is there a way to check if "-list" argument was passed at all?

Comment: The standard library flags package does not allow the caller to determine if a flag value was explicitly set, or if the default value was arrived at. For this you'd need to investigate third party flag packages.

Comment: P.S. I have not used the flag package [viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper), but it does seem to support checks for explicitly user settings of flags (even if the user chooses the default value).